# Require user based on URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, authorization

I'd like to require user `user1` when the URL is `/foo/user1/*`, user `user2` when the URL is `/foo/user2/*`, etc.  Is it possible to do this?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
AliasMatch ^/foo/([^/]+)(/.*)? /home/$1/foo$2
<LocationMatch "^/foo/([^/]+)(/.*)?">
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic                                                              
    AuthName "foo"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
    Require user $1
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Does http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html (Per-user web directories) help at all?

Comment: @jimbobmcgee:  The `UserDir` directive appears to only support `/~user/*` and it doesn't appear to support any authentication/authorization.

Comment: Not sure re the `~` (perhaps you can abstract it with `mod_rewrite`), but wouldn't a `.htaccess` file with one Require User statement in each real folder do the trick for authentication?

Comment: Using `mod_rewrite` to rewrite to a `UserDir` certainly works - I've been doing this for years to have `users.example.com/user1` rather than `server.example.com/~user`, therefore you could either put a `.htaccess` in each user's `public_html` or do something clever with the `Require` directive in `mod_userdir`.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman: That "something clever with the `Require` directive in `mod_userdir`" is the core of my question.  Any thoughts on how to do that?  I don't want to have to remember to put an `.htaccess` in each user's directory -- that's not fail-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming files in `/home/user1/fooX` are owned by `user1` you could consider [`mod_authz_owner`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_owner.html) and use `Require file-owner`.

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "User files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
  Satisfy All
  Require file-owner
</Directory>
```

Comment: Accepting because in my case the files are owned by the user in question, but I'd really love to see an answer that would work even if the files were not owned by the user.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's possible. You can use `SetEnvIf` to set a user environment variable that can be used by `Allow` or `Deny`, but `Require` won't accept this.